# How to reference images from a Google Firestore?

Tags: image, google-cloud-firestore

My app use a Google cloud Firestore instance. Among the data my App manages there some classical data (string, number, ...): No problem with that / Firestore handle these use case easily.
But my app also need to consume images that are linked to the other data.
So I'm looking for the right solution to manage images.: I try to use the "reference" type Field from my Firestore instance but I'm not sure that the right way...

Is there another solution outside Firestore?

What about Google cloud Filestore?: It seems available only from an app engine or a VM...

I try to use the "reference" type Field from my Firestore instance but I'm not sure that the right way...

Is there another solution outside Firestore?

What about Google cloud Filestore?: It seems available only from an app engine or a VM...

Comment: You need a place to store the images or just storing the URL or IDs of this images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclosure: I work on the Firebase team at Google.*

When I want to use both structured and unstructured data in my application, I use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) for the structured data, and [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) for the unstructured data. I use both of these through their Firebase SDKs, so that I can access the data and files directly from within my application code, or from server-side code (typically running in Cloud Functions).

There is no built-in reference type between Firestore and Storage, so you'll need to manage that yourself. I usually store either the path to the image in Firestore, or the [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) of the image. The choice between these two mostly depends on whether I want the file to be publicly accessible, or whether access needs to be controlled more tightly.

Since there is no managed relationship between Firestore and Storage (or any other Firebase/Google Cloud Platform services), you'll need to manage this yourself. This means that you'll need to write the related data (like the path above), check for its integrity when reading it (and handle corrupt data gracefully), and consider periodically running a script that removes/fixes up corrupt data.

Comment: Just one subsequent question : When you talk about "strorage", which GCP solution  do you mean exactly ? Typically, is it a "FileStore" instance ? A "Bucket" ?... I'm new  to GCP and there are many ways for every use case.

Comment: @DavidVidal the product itself it's called "storage", the full name would be "Goodle Cloud Storage" https://cloud.google.com/storage here you save your files in "buckets"

Comment: Cloud Storage for Firebase. I provided a link in my answer.